# Cookies are sometimes not sent after a redirect in mobile Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, cookies, safari, webkit

I have an issue with my Spring-Boot based, web-application and mobile browsers behaving very strange when a link in Gmail is selected.

The valid flow, which works on most devices and browsers (on iOS, Android, OSX, etc.):

1. User clicks on a link in the Gmail application.
2. User is asked which browser the link should be opened in, selects Chrome.
3. `GET /path-01` - results in `302` to `/path-02` and `Set-Cookie` header with `JSESSIONID=01`.
4. `GET /path-02` - results in `200` and a session with ID `01` is restored.

The invalid flow, which appears *sometimes* on iOS 13 with Chrome version: `81.0.4044.124` <s>and supposedly on Safari browser and even on Android with Chrome browser (sadly, I was not able to determine versions for any of them)</s>:

1. User clicks on a link in the Gmail application.
2. User is asked which browser the link should be opened in, selects Chrome.
3. `GET /path-01` - results in `302` to `/path-02` and `Set-Cookie` header with `JSESSIONID=01`.
4. `GET /path-01` - results in `302` to `/path-02` and `Set-Cookie` header with `JSESSIONID=02`.
5. `GET /path-02` - results in `200` and `Set-Cookie` header with `JSESSIONID=03` because there were no Cookies sent along the request.
6. `GET /path-02` - results in `200` and `Set-Cookie` header with `JSESSIONID=04` because there were no Cookies sent along the request.

This odd behavior with double requests and no Cookies being sent after a redirect are causing my flow to break because `/path-02` expects a value in session which is not there since a new one has been created. The invalid flow appears only **sometimes**, which is also frustrating. So far I have not found any relation of why is that so.

I have also experimented with the `SameSite` attribute being set to each of the possible values and invalid flow appears sometimes on each of these settings anyway.

It is also worth mentioning that after clicking on a link in Gmail, a user is being redirected through `https://www.google.com/url?q=https://example.com/path-01&source=gmail&ust=1588944764533000&usg=AFQoCNECXqm1HdH9o66Iu1wD_VnOPE6Q6p`.

**Update**
The issue presents itself when there is another card with the URL to the same site, but different path, already open. Then, when a user taps a link in Gmail, the browser opens and the card in the background also seem to go to the same URL the second one goes to and additionally no cookies are sent for both of those requests. The issue can only be reproduced on iOS, on both Chrome and Safari browsers.